# Check size of string and depending on size, manipulate it?

Tags: shell, sh

I have tried dong this my self but I have failed miserably, but this is basically what I am trying to achieve in sh (#!/bin/sh):

sudo code

```
SOMEVAR="VALUE"

if [ $SOMEVAR.length > 5]
then 
# Take the first 5 characters of the string and add "HIS" to the end of them, assigning this new value to the SOMEVAR variable. 
else
#just add "HIS" to the end of the string
fi
```

if someone can tell me how i can achieve this it would be greatly appreciated, I have tried using ${#SOMEVAR} > 5 and ${SOMEVAR:0:5} but this dosnet work for me.

thanks

Comment: are you really using 'sh' (Bourne Shell, on an old-line Unix vendor platform)? Or do you want to retag this with bash or ksh or ??? Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have it work in Bourne, you can use:

```
#!/bin/sh
SOMEVAR="HELLO WORLD"
if [ ${#SOMEVAR} -gt 5 ]
then
    SOMEVAR=`expr substr "$SOMEVAR" 1 5`    
fi
SOMEVAR="${SOMEVAR}HIS"
```

Comment: +1, but since "expr substr foo 1 5" prints "foo", you can skip the length check and just do SOMEVAR=$( expr substr "$SOMEVAR" 1 5 )HIS

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a version of Bourne that can do this in one line without invoking any other commands like `expr`:

```
SOMEVAR=${SOMEVAR:0:5}HIS
```

But if your shell doesn't support that fancy substring extraction syntax, you could use sed. (Note that not all versions of `expr` support substr.)

```
SOMEVAR=`echo "$SOMEVAR" | sed 's/^\(.....\).*/\1/'`HIS
```